# Tuple in function argument list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arguments, tuples

I have old Python 2 code that contains

```
def __init__(self, (gv_to_python, python_to_gv), values, bgl_type='object') :
```

Using this in Python 3 gives a syntax error (2to3 can't fix this).

What is the Python 3 equivalent of this Python 2 function definition?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 2):

[PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) indicates that tuple parameters are being removed. The transition plan at the bottom of that page suggests

> Second, the 2to3 refactoring tool [1] will gain a fixer [2] for
>   translating tuple parameters to being a single parameter that is
>   unpacked as the first statement in the function. The name of the new
>   parameter will be changed. The new parameter will then be unpacked
>   into the names originally used in the tuple parameter. This means that
>   the following function:
>
> ```
> def fxn((a, (b, c))):
>     pass
> ```
>
> will be translated into:
>
> ```
> def fxn(a_b_c):
>     (a, (b, c)) = a_b_c
>     pass
> ```

Basically, change the parameter into a single value, and unpack it in the body of your function.